# WP7 open email+account pager by code

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, email, account

is it possible open [email+account page](http://www.wingadgetnews.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/wp7-add-outlook-2.jpg)  programmatically from my own App, to let user create a new social account?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible.
You can launch only [few tasks](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/iersoy/task-system-in-windows-phone-7/)

- Camera Capture Task
- Email Address Chooser Task
- MarketPlace Search Task
- MarketPlace Hub Task
- MediaPlayer Launcher
- Phone Call Task
- Phone Number Chooser Task
- Photo Chooser Task
- Search Task
- SMS Compose Task
- WebBrowser Task

Comment: While this is true, you can use a WebBrowser task, or a WebBrowser control (the former is recommended) to direct the user to the required page.